# GET request error: postData.posts.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve a logged-in user's specific shipping information from mongodb. The console.log(req.params.id) in app.js outputs the user's id so the information is being received on the backend. `console.log(documents)`in app.js returns correct information from database, but I get a message`postData.posts.map is not a function"``` that is thrown because of my service.ts

Why is this error being thrown?

profile.service.ts

```
  getShippingInformation(id: string) {

    return this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: any; maxPosts: number }>(
        `http://localhost:3000/api/users/${id}`
      )
      .pipe(
        map(postData => {
      console.log("postData");
      console.log(postData);
          return {
            posts: postData.posts.map(post => {
              return {
                fullName: post.fullName,
                address1: post.address1,
                address2: post.address2,
                city: post.city,
                state: post.state,
                zip: post.zip
              };
            }),
            maxPosts: postData.maxPosts
          };
        })
      );
  }
```

profile.component.ts

```
 this.profileService.getShippingInformation(this.userId).subscribe((res) => {

      this.shippingInfo = res.posts;
      console.log("shippinginfo");
      console.log(this.shippingInfo);

      if (res.posts[0].fullName === "Not Added Yet") {
        this.hideShippingData = false;

      }
      else {
        this.hideShippingData = true;
        this.fullName = res.posts[0].fullName;
        this.address1 = res.posts[0].address1;
        this.address2 = res.posts[0].address2;
        this.city = res.posts[0].city;
        this.state = res.posts[0].state;
        this.zip = res.posts[0].zip;
      }
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
```

app.js

```
app.get("/api/users/:id", (req, res, next) => {
console.log("req.params.id");
console.log(req.params.id);
  if (req.params.id) {
    console.log("MADE IT TO USER SECTION");
    console.log(req.params.id);
  }
  User.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
    .select("fullName address1 address2 city state zip")
    .then(documents => {
     console.log(documents);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "User account located!",
        posts: documents
      });
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: could you show what the value of `postData` is

Comment: Stop using `any`. Look at what the server actually sends back, write an in interface matching that structure, and you won't be able anymore to call methods that don't exist.

Comment: I added 2 console.logs in code above to reflect screenshot.

Comment: So, as you see, `posts` is not an array. It's an object. And objects don't have a map() method. Hence the error/

Comment: I think I sorted it out now. Thanks for the tips. The only thing I don't understand in my specific scenario is what to use instead of ```any``` If I put anything else, I get errors

Comment: You define an interface containing the properties of the object and their type, and you use that. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks!